# Accessing IIS's request handling pipeline to inject a request and get the html response

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is it at all possible to inject a request into IIS for a page, have IIS and ASP.Net handle it as normal, but get the response as html handed back to me programmatically?

Yes, I know that I could connect to port 80 using WebRequest and WebResponse, but that becomes difficult if you are accessing the IIS server from the same physical machine (loopback security controls et al).

Basically, I want to inject the request (eg for http://example.org/MyPage.aspx) between the points at which IIS would normally talk to the browser, and the point at which it would route it to the correct ASP.Net application, and get a response back from IIS between the points at which ASP.Net/IIS applies the httpfilters and hands the html back to the browser.

I'm predominantly working with IIS7 so if there is a solution that works just for IIS7 then thats not an issue.

Comment: What do you need it for? If you specify, I have got a few ideas in mind.

Comment: What loopback security control? There's nothing that I'm aware of that, by default, prevents you from accessing sites running on the local server. Heck I do it every day.

Comment: @blowdart http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642

Comment: @blowdart http://sptwentyten.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/disable-the-loopback-check-via-powershell/

Comment: And no, I dont want to use the above links to disable the check :)

Comment: But it's only if you use the FQDN - if you use http://localhost it'll work fine.

Comment: Localhost doesn't help me when there is more than one site hosted....

Comment: What about setting up host names within .HOSTS? If those don't have a ., so they look like intranet addresses it may well work.

Comment: @blowdart - that won't work because you are still accessing the server using a different name from the localhost.  Believe me, I've looked at ways to resolve this before opening the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a custom HttpModule, which would give you access to the IIS pipeline, including the final response. However, you would still need to initiate a request to IIS to actually kick off processing. Not sure if this would work for you.

From [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb398986%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> An HTTP module is an assembly that is
>   called on every request that is made
>   to your application. HTTP modules are
>   called as part of the request pipeline
>   and have access to life-cycle events
>   throughout the request. HTTP modules
>   therefore let you examine incoming
>   requests and take action based on the
>   request. They also let you examine the
>   outgoing response and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Gave you looked into the WebCkiebt class? You can make the request and get the response HTML.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Has the same issue as I mention above - if you connect to http://example.org/ and both yourself and http://example.org reside on the same server, Windows and IIS will prevent the request for security reasons.